# Swift - Subclassed UICollectionViewCell not loading IBOutlet properties

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I come from Obj-C and I'm struggling on doing something super basic in Swift!

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    // Outlets
    // ***************************

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    // Init
    // ***************************

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)

        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setup()
    }

    func setup()
    {
        button.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

The cell is loaded from an external .xib file, so `init(coder:)` is called for the initialization but my button is not ready.

If I change to `button?.backgroundColor` the app doesn't crash but obviously nothing happen.

I can call my `setup()` function in `layoutSubviews()` and it works, but it's definitely not the right place to be.

How do I solve this massive problem? lol

**Edit**

Probably I have to call `setup()` from `awakeFromNib()`, right?
I usually don't use external .xib, I'm not familiar with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry It seems youe edited your question before my answer, it seems as you load it from XIB, then you can run the awakeFromNib which will be called when you **register a nib** using this method:

[Apple Source UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-register)

[Apple Source UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614937-registernib)

--- old post below ---

> In Xcode 6 you have to provide additional init(coder:) initializer in
>   classes like RDCell, which is the subclass of UICollectionViewCell.
>   This initializer is called instead of init(frame:) when the class gets
>   initialized from a storyboard or a xib file. That’s not our case, but
>   we still need to provide init(coder:). We can use the solution
>   provided to us by Xcode. In Issue Navigator click on an error that
>   says “'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by
>   subclass of 'UICollectionViewCell'“,

[Source](https://randexdev.com/2014/08/uicollectionviewcell/)

Comment: Yeah I just realised that, monday morning dammit! :) thanks

Comment: @JacopoPenzo I feel you! :) np man , GL, btw , register it once only in "viewDidLoad" of your VC , if you have the same reuseIdentifier, otherwise you need to register it once for every unique identifier.

Comment: I'm using 'IGListKit', so no dramma on registrations :)